# s.tk minor bug for podcast/podcasts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, s.tk

[s.tk/podcast](http://s.tk/podcast) redirects to [podcasts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/),
[s.tk/podcasts](http://s.tk/podcasts) doesn't

It's cosmetic, but I guessed it might not be deliberate...

<sup>Please don't [hit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) me</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was deliberate, but it seems like a popular request, so its been addded